# How to bind Enum Values In vaadin flow?

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow

In my vaadin flow project with springboot I faced a problem that enum values with combo box cannot be bind.
I provided my code below. Anyone here who can help me out?

Combobox instantiation:

```
private ComboBox<Country> nationality = new CompoBox<>("Nationality");
```

Binding code:

```
binder.forField(nationality)
    .bind(Coach::getNationality,Coach:setNationality);
```

Comment: Please don't provide _images_ of your code here.  Paste the relevant parts in your question.  It helps answering the question better and it makes your question searchable.

Answer (score 9):

I think you are missing the `setItems` call. Here is an example based on the [Project Base for Vaadin Flow](https://github.com/vaadin/skeleton-starter-flow)

```java
package com.vaadin.starter.skeleton;

import com.vaadin.flow.component.button.Button;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.combobox.ComboBox;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.notification.Notification;
import com.vaadin.flow.component.orderedlayout.VerticalLayout;
import com.vaadin.flow.data.binder.Binder;
import com.vaadin.flow.router.Route;
import com.vaadin.flow.server.PWA;

/**
 * The main view contains a button and a click listener.
 */
@Route("")
@PWA(name = "Project Base for Vaadin Flow", shortName = "Project Base")
public class MainView extends VerticalLayout {

    public MainView() {

        ComboBox<ENUM> comboBox = new ComboBox<ENUM>("Number");
        comboBox.setItems(ENUM.values());
        Binder<Bean> binder = new Binder<>();
        binder.setBean(new Bean());
        binder.bind(comboBox,Bean::getField,Bean::setField);
        Button button = new Button("Check value",
                        e-> Notification.show("Value in bean is " + binder.getBean().getField()));
        add(button,comboBox);
    }

    public enum ENUM {
        ONE,TWO,TREE
    }

    public static class Bean {
        private ENUM field;

        public ENUM getField() {

            return field;
        }

        public void setField(ENUM field) {

            this.field = field;
        }
    }
}
```